# attempting to check whether an image is on a page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image on my webpage as follows:

```
<img id="k4Tbx6luuHmP01dpI4BRZw==" src="/thumbnail/k4Tbx6luuHmP01dpI4BRZw==">
```

However, when I try

```
var is_image_there = $("#k4Tbx6luuHmP01dpI4BRZw==").attr("src");
console.log(is_image_there);
```

Chrome console returns "undefined". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `=` disallowed in Id's

Comment: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: @Oybek: Actually, [that is allowed in HTML5](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class). You just need to [escape the ID value correctly](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) when using it in a selector.

Comment: @MathiasBynens. Good point. And thanks for the tool btw :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [escape the selector correctly](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes):

```
$('#k4Tbx6luuHmP01dpI4BRZw\\=\\=');
```

Here’s a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mathias/crYWH/

To check if the image is there or not, you can check the `.length` property:

```
$('#k4Tbx6luuHmP01dpI4BRZw\\=\\=').length;
```

This will be equal to `0` if the image is not in the page.

I’ve made a tool that will help you escape any selector correctly: [mothereff.in/css-escapes](http://mothereff.in/css-escapes#0k4Tbx6luuHmP01dpI4BRZw%3D%3D) Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this tool Mathias - it's a lifesaver! I am using the html5 doctype but wasn't aware of id restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it seems to work if you [escape](http://jsbin.com/apasoq/2/edit) the `=`.
As I understand, id is a base 64 string. 
I can advice you to just remove padding, i.e. `=`. Then restore them when you need.

It is simple, base 64 string must be of lenght 4*n. If it is not equal to it then it is padded with `=`.

Furthermore, your url also contains `=`. this is a special character in url. Hence I suggest you to use [url based base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications).

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to have == in your id as far as you are NOT using html5.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Actually, that is allowed in HTML5. See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class.

Comment: yeah but when it's returing undefined I don't think that he is using the right doctype for html5

Comment: It doesn’t matter what DOCTYPE the OP uses. HTML5 just standardized what browsers already supported in this aspect. Here’s a demo of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/mathias/crYWH/

Comment: but using the doctype declares in which standard the page is developed and the browser has to "read" the document.

Comment: Browser behavior is the same as long as you’re in standards mode; which DOCTYPE is used exactly doesn’t really matter as long as it triggers standards mode.